# C# import MS-Access database into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I need to import data from a MS Access database into a SQl Server 2000 database once a day. Since I need this to be done every day automated is there a c# routine which would be able to do this?

The tables in the MS Access database will be named as the same tables in the SQL Server and it needs to delete the tables in the SQL Server database and then import the new data/tables from MS Access.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)

Comment: There is no automatic process that I know of (in C#).  are these tables going to be large?  It may affect the choice of solution.

Comment: yes some of them are going to be

Comment: I could do it so it is triggered by clicking a button instead of being automated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps:

1 - Create a LinkedServer in SQLServer like this:
    `EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'Customers', @srvproduct = 'CustomersDB', @provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', @datasrc = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp\AccessDB.MDB', @location = '', @provstr = '', @catalog = ''`
    `EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server = 'Customers', @optname = 'collation compatible', @optvalue = 'false'` 

2 - Create a stored procedure inside your target sqlserver doing the import work
    `CREATE PROCEDURE ImportMDBData`
    `as`
        `TRUNCATE TABLE sqlServerCustTable`
        `INSERT INTO sqlServerCustTable (list your columns name here) (SELECT * FROM Customers.dbo.mdbCustTable)`

3 - Now you just need to call the stored procedure from your code

Comment: Sorry ive never created a stored procedure, and in the above what do i have to replace with what? my two databases currently are called accessDB and sqlDB..the accessDB is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp

Comment: Also do i need a stored procedure per table then? i have 11 tables

Comment: well, you should replace (list your columns name here) with the column names of your sqlserver table. No you don't need a stored procedure for each table, simply repeat the TRUNCATE and SELECT INTO statements changing the name of the relevant table into the same stored procedure

Comment: ok and in step one, i dont really understand what it means the two db's are on the same server

Comment: OK I think I have made some assumptions here: First you need to use SQLServer Management Studio and connect to your sql server database and issue the commands in step 1 and step 2.

Comment: Ok and when it says @server do i leave it as Customers? and srvproduct shouldnt this be accessdb?

Comment: The names are used only to illustrate the operations involved. You could rename them as you wish. (Of course you should reflect the change in the stored procedure)

Comment: ok i will give it a go and its .accdb not mdb hope that doesnt make a difference

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8064/discussion-between-beginner-and-steve)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a stored procedure in your sql server database to do it, see here:
[select from access database file and insert to sql Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145270/select-from-access-database-file-and-insert-to-sql-database)

As was mentioned by marc_s you may be able to use SSIS - but there could be quite a bit of learning involved in getting that right.

Another option is to control it from within C# - pulling data from the access DB and then inserting it into the sql server - this is unlikely to be what you want.

If your access db and the sql server instance are guaranteed to be on the same server then I would be inclined to try option 1.  If not then it opens up dozens of additional questions ;)

EDIT:
you mention it can be done by clicking a button - in this case really you should give the SSIS solution a once over at least and see if it looks like what you want, it is designed for exactly this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

access.mdb linked servers in sql server any versions, it should be needed Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 or Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. those drivers are existed two types 32 bit and 64 bit. 64 bit os prefer install 64 bit jet drivers other wise linking not may work.