# Ways to import from MS Access to SQL Server for large datasets

Tags: c#, import, datatable, out-of-memory, oledb

So I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2013.  I currently have an importer that uses System.Data.OleDb to connect to MS Access databases and System.Data.SqlClient for the Sql Server connection.

What I originally was doing was I would read data from MS Access and store tables in a DataTable and store the data in the DataTable into SQL Server.  It was doing well until I finally hit a table with some 30 odd columns and almost 1 million rows and I got an OutOfMemoryException.

So now I'm attempting to think of a work around.  I am thinking of setting a row count check on an MS Access table before I attempt to load into a DataTable and if it is a certain number of rows or higher I plan to attempt to write to an external file and then do an import on that file.

So what I'm asking is anyone know how I can go about this?  Only solutions I've seen use Interop and I've heared as a practice you don't want to use interop in code because its slow and not terribly reliable.  I was attempting to get an import from MS Access to a .csv or .txt file, but if a table doesn't have a Primary Key I'm not sure how to go about iterating over a table if it's not currently in a DataTable.

Comment: have you looked at how to Link Access to a Sql Server table..this can be done very easily have you tried any google searches.. I know this is possible because I've done this before many times.. also can this also be done in chunks based on a particular record count or number of records.. 
also look up how to use DTS or SSIS

Comment: then I would suggest looking into SSIS, or perhaps writing some query where you can insert the data from Access into SQL still the same did you try googling..?

Comment: I don't want to keep data on MS Access. SQL Server provides data backup, security, more storage, etc. So I don't want to do a link where it's still on Access but viewable on SQL Server...  I mentioned that I know how to do it in chunks if there's a PK, but if no PK I don't know how to get sections of a table at a time without it being in something like a DataTable.  Which in this case the MS Access table is to large to be stored in a DataTable...

Comment: Yes I did google.  I mentioned above that I saw methods people used to do import with Interop to go strait from Access to a XLS file, but I'd prefer not to use Interop.

Comment: if you prefer to use Interop.. can you show what you have tried thus far so we can see.. you have to make an effort here this site is not a code factory site.. personally I would create my own parser routine and do the inserts.. using a class.. there are several ways you can approach this ..

Comment: "Only solutions I've seen use Interop and I've heared as a practice you don't want to use interop in code because its slow and not terribly reliable." No interop.

Comment: check out this option this would seem to work for you.. assuming you are familiar with creating and using stored procedures http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145270/select-from-access-database-file-and-insert-to-sql-database

Comment: I do not think the Server admin will allow for changes on the server unless it's absolutly necessary.  Also I'm not sure if that solution is Jet reliant or not...I'll need some time to look at the SSIS though so thanks for that piece.

Comment: SSIS doesn't look like it would scale well for many MS Access databases with various and different tables and contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing an import on large data, you could use and **OleDbReader**. When using an OleDbReader, it would not affect your memory as you would read through one record at a time to do the insert into another database.

It may take slightly longer, but will ensure completion without an OutOfMemory Error.

Comment: I'll need some time to test this, but that sounds good thanks.

Comment: Done it before on a couple of projects, when I hit the same problems you have. Should work :)